# What's the origin of "по первое число"?

Tags: этимология, выражения

This phrase *по первое число*, meaning "large amount", is usually used when describing a punishment or generally an unpleasant experience

e.g.

> Завалило снегом **по первое число**.
>   Получил от начальства **по первое число**.

**What is the origin/etymology of this phrase?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An excerpt by [gramota.ru](http://goo.gl/NZoDm) from *Бирих А. К., Мокиенко В. М., Степанова Л. И. Русская фразеология. Историко-этимологический словарь / Под ред. В. М. Мокиенко.*:

> *По первое число всыпать (прописать)* — сильно наказать кого-нибудь. Выражение восходит к старинной практике пороть ученика. Каждую неделю пороли ученика, вне зависимости от того, виноват он или нет. Если пороли сильно, то порки хватало на последующие недели вплоть до первого числа следующего месяца.

Other sources suggest that it was a precausion measure: if a student had been beaten too hard he was excepted from corporal punishment till the first of the next month.

First mention (in this sense) in the corpus:

> ― Кабы не ты, ну наклали бы они мне по первое число! *[Ф. Д. Крюков. Казачка // «Русское Богатство», 1896]*

, in Google Books:

> А на другой день уже по всей окрестности разносилась молва, что Сангуровские садовники поймали Андрюшку Егозу, "нашвыряли ему в загорбок по первое число" и ещё на всю ночь привязали его к яблоньке. *[«Русский Вестник», т. 258, вып. 1, стр. 147, 1898]*

Answer (score 2):

При царе в гимназиях , школах и семинариях были распространены и узаконены розги (физические наказания детей за проступки). Иногда били просто так для профилактики и укрепления дисциплины. Если педагог входил в раж (перебарщивал , перебирал) и ребёнок получал слишком большую дозу розог то до 1-го числа следующего месяца освобождался от физических наказаний. Эта экзекуция с излишним количеством розог и называлась "всыпать по первое число".

Comment: Welcome to Russian Language and Usage Beta! While probably being legit, your answer does not seem to add to the answers given by the other users. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://russian.stackexchange.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is our way of saying "thank you, I like this answer, I agree with it". Duplicate answers [will be removed](http://russian.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion).

Comment: @Olga It is not a duplicate answer, the first answer is incorrect in its Russian part. Because of bad Russian. So, one answer is correct in English, another in Russian.